# Substring NSString upto limited number of character after occurrence of specific character?

Tags: ios, nsstring, substring

I have distance in following format.

```
36.5067714083419
```

I want two character after occurrence of dot "."
So the above String must look like

```
36.50
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an `NSString`? By judging the name and the value of the variable I would suggest using a `float`. Then you can just do the following:

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];
```

Comment: The variable that you want formatted. Why are you using a String instead of a double, long or float?

Comment: It was NSString, well I did like this 
float myFloat = [distance floatValue];
        
        distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];

Comment: Even better than using `stringWithFormat:` is to use `NSNumberFormatter` so the decimal value appears correctly regardless of the user's locale.